# How do you get to the value inside of a python function that returns nothing for unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test for an existing function:

```
def _fetch_law(self, task, storage):
    number, link = task
    if not self.silent:
        print 'Requesting page %s' % number
    r = requests.get(link, headers=self.headers)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        sys.exit('CONNECTION ERROR!!! HTTP ERROR %d' % r.status_code)
    vs = LawPages(r.text)
    storage.extend(vs.extract())
```

For my unit testing, how do I use mocking or other means to get to the final value that is passed to storage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use the `mock` library (`unittest.mock` in python3.x).  It would look something like:

```
mock_storage = mock.Mock()
obj._fetch_law(some_task, mock_storage)
mock_storage.extend.assert_called_with(expected_value)
```

Of course, in this example, you might want to mock out requests as well...  `mock.patch` is great for that:

```
with mock.patch.object(requests, 'get') as mock_get:
    mock_get.return_value = ' ... '
    mock_storage = mock.Mock()
    obj._fetch_law(some_task, mock_storage)
    mock_storage.extend.assert_called_with(expected_value)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are passing `storage` to the function, why don't you just create an empty list which you pass on. The function will append to `storage` and you can then check, what is in that list and if it is the expected result.

Comment: that depends on the type of the return value `vs.extract` -- it would have to be iterable (note, the function uses `extend`, not `append`).

Comment: @mgilson i don't see the problem. if the list is empty and then filled by this function, all data in the list must come from that list. as we don't know how this data looks like, it is hard to specify how to check

Comment: @mgilson that is true, however function defines it with `extend()`, so if it is not iterable, the code will fail. but that if a different problem than testing if something was written into a list

Comment: that depends critically on the object `storage`.  `storage.extend` could work with non-iterable data.  As written, this problem is underspecified since we know nothing about the storage object that will be passed.  If OP's use-case actually uses a list-like object, then I agree -- use a `list` :-).

Comment: ah, i now see where you are coming from. yes, in that case i just assumed the storage is a list ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lawrence is correct, just do something simple like:

```
def test_fetch_law():
    store = []
    task = ...
    cls = ClassWithFetchLaw()
    cls._fetch_law(task, store)
    assert len(store) > 0
```

On another note, if you're going down the unit test route, why not have the sys.exit throw an exception and write another test for it? Unless you really want the sys.exit in there...

```
def test_fetch_law_throws():
    store = []
    bad_task = ...
    cls = ClassWithFetchLaw()
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        cls._fetch_law(bad_task, store)
```